# Grub2 of previous OS controls the boot process

Tags: multi-boot, centos-7, grub2, ubuntu-16.04

I have 3 OS's on my computer.

First, I installed windows 10.

Secondly, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with GUI).

Thirdly, CentOS 7 (without GUI).

During Ubuntu installation, I installed Grub2 into MBR and it was taking care of booting.

Then, during CentOS installation I again installed Grub2 into MBR, so that CentOS controls booting. And it was controlling for a year or so.

However, recently, I've used such commands as apt-update and apt-upgrade while on Ubuntu system, and now the boot process is controlled by Ubuntu. How do I know ? Well, when the booting process starts and I get to choose which OS I want to load, the background of the menu is in Ubuntu colors. Previously, when CentOS installation based Grub2 was in control of booting everything was in black and white.

How do I make CentOS Grub2 be responsible for the booting process again ?

I've tried to login to CentOS and do something like :

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

But this didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you chose to install grub for both Linux distros you end up in a "winner takes it all" situation: Whichever GRUB is reinstalled last (e.g. because of an update in the distro) controlls the boot process.

By running `install-grub /dev/sdX` in the distro of your choice you can force it to be the current winner - until the next update. If you want to make sure Ubuntu takes over never again, just uninstall GRUB or add `grub` to the update blacklist